# Pushed child view controller adds unwanted status bar

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, statusbar

I am trying to update some code for iOS 7.  I created a view controller and I have it animated in when you click on a button. vc is declared in the .h file.

When you click the button the following code is run:

```
vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[vc.view setBounds:self.view.bounds];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

It then adds a new status bar which is unwanted.

Any ideas on how to remove it?

Pictures were asked for so here they are:

This is the nav bar of the screen with the button:
[image]

This is the nav bar in the next screen:
[image]

Comment: Will you please upload an image,

Comment: I added two images of the nav bar.

Comment: I have a work around by creating a uiviewcontroller in the storyboard but I'd like to solve this with code.